# querystring parser

Tags: jquery, regex

Simple querystring pattern that I am unsure of how to parse: always a '-' with one letter followed by 8 numbers and '?'

URL:
-A10080008?

perhaps something like:
'['-_A-Z0-9']?';
or
(|-|[A-Z1-9]))).?)

Answer (score 0):

```
"-A10080008?".match(/-A\d+8\?/)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
`-[A-Za-z]\d{8}\?`
`-` : always one '-'
`[A-Za-z]` : a letter
`\d{8}` : eight digits
`\?` : a '?'
Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/jYi45F/1)